# How do I return the normal ToC format?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tcolorbox, mdframed, titletoc

I use a styled section format with `titlesec` (and `mdframed`, but it also happens with `tcolorbox`), and it change the style of the TOC.
**How I return it to the normal style?** *(see picture and file below)*

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,hebrew,american]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ,framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}
%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12.8}{14}\selectfont}
%  {}{0pt}
%  {\begin{tcolorbox}\thesection\hskip0.7em#1\end{tcolorbox}}[]


\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{backgroundcolor=gray!40,shadow=true,roundcorner=8pt}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12.8}{14}\selectfont}
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle]\thesection\hskip0.7em#1\end{mdframed}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

\section{abcd}

\tableofcontents{}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `numberless` key: this code only removes the `mdframed` box

```
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}%
{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12.8}{14}\selectfont}{}{0pt}{#1}
```

but you also can modify the other features and also modify the spacing  for unnumbered sections with `\titlespacing{name=\section,numberless}{...}`.

For the fully normal toc format (i.e. the normal section format), use

```
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1}
```

Comment: Where I need to put this code? Thank you!

Comment: In the preamble. Note  all unnumbered sections (bibliography, index, glossary, list of tables, &c.) will follow this layout.